# Last value of a column QuerySet API (Django)

Tags: mysql, django, django-queryset

I want to get the last value of a column. How can I get it? A traslation to Django queryset of `SELECT column_name FROM table_name ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`. This works fine in MySQL but I don't get to find the equivalent one in Django. Suggestions? Solutions?

Before, it was a queryset that generated a queryset like this: `SELECT MAX(column_name) FROM table_name WHERE column_name_2 = x`, but it took so long and I wanna change.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is probably that a `[-1]` index (which in python means "get the last item") doesn't work on querysets:

```
> YourModel.objects.order_by('id')[-1]
Traceback
...
AssertionError: Negative indexing is not supported.
```

The simple solution is to reverse the order and get the first one, which is exactly what you do in your hand-written SQL:

```
> YourModel.objects.order_by('-id')[0]
<YourModel....>
```

Putting a `-` in front of a column name reverses the sort order. So that's probably the hint you need.

Since Django 1.6 there are special `.first()` and `.last()` methods on querysets, see [Django's docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.first). It'd look like this for you:

```
> YourModel.objects.order_by('id').last()
<YourModel....>
```

Next up, you want to get just the value. Django has `.values()` and `.values_list()` for that. I often use `.values_list('some single field', flat=True)` if I just want a list of single values. In your case:

```
> YourModel.objects.order_by('id').values_list('column_name', 
                                               flat=True).last()
1234
```

Of course, just grabbing the value from the object is shorter in this case:

```
> YourModel.objects.order_by('id').last().column_name
1234
```

Comment: What you say is equivalent to `SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`. But, from this object, how can I get the value of one single column? -> `SELECT column_name FROM table_name ORDER BY...`

Comment: Ok, got it. I get first the object and then one of its fields. I apologyze for my incredible big ignorance. And thank you very much!

Comment: Ah, you're right. I've extended my answer to get out just the value. Tip: experiment a while with Django's `values()` and `values_list()`. At least, it took me a while to get familiar with it. Especially in combination with `.annotate()`, as that performs automatic grouping when used together with `.values()`. Powerful, but it takes some getting used to.

Comment: I'll do it. Thanks for the tip! ;)

Comment: Regarding "first get the object and then one of the fields": in this case it would have been the quickest way. In other cases, `.values_list()` can be handiest. I've edited the answer again to include the "just grab the field from the object" alternative.

Answer (score 0):

The  equivalent will be following:

```
YourModel.objects.order_by('column_name')[0]
```

See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets) for documentation.

Comment: He wants it ordered by `id`, not `column_name`. And he wants the last, not the first value.

Comment: well id is a column name too

Comment: You're right. The question could be worded better, 'column_name' is too generic and makes talking about this harder :-). His SQL ("which works") contains `ORDER BY id DESC`, which I took to mean "order by id".